# How can I take a full screenshot of the Pokedex?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm trying to take the full screenshot of the pokedex in Pokemon Go but I couldn't figure out how do it. I've tried many different tools which all ended up unsuccessful. The best solution seems to be stitching different parts of the pokedex which looks bad because the purple-pink background doesn't shift when sliding the pokedex and also the slider does repeat on different parts of it. Tools which have the ability of taking scrolling windows seem to be unable to identify the scroll of the pokedex window.

There are some pokedex screenshots in the wild which seem to have been taken with some kind of scrolling window solution which makes me curious about the method or tool they are using. Does anyone know of a trick or tool which captures the entire pokedex into a single screenshot?

Comment: Some smartphones have the ability to take scrolling pictures. It's highly likely the pictures you've seen were taken by a smartphone like that. It might've also been done by people who use gaming capture hardware and/or software.

Comment: If using software to stitch multiple screenshots, why not also crop off the repeated background and slider?

Answer (score 2):

The game doesn't have an option for that in-game.

Other discussions apart from that are off-topic on this page.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is not with a direct screen capture, but with stitching together a series of screen captures in a photo program such as Gimp an online photo manipulation site.

Comment: I think the OP already knows this, since they specifically mentioned this method in their question.

Comment: So it would seem.